# Hilchos Barech Aleinu in the Summer

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shemoneh-esrei, shulchan-aruch, contemporary-halacha

Where does the Shulchan Aruch discuss if someone mistakenly asked for rain in in Barech Aleinu instead of saying "Vesein Beracha" and what is his ruling?

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Arukh discusses the law of one who accidentally requested rain in the summer in [OC 117](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%96):2-3. He rules that if that happened in a country that didn't need rain at the time, the prayer must be repeated; however, if it happened in a country that indeed needed rain at that time, the prayer need not be repeated (but it can be repeated voluntarily).

Comment: The latter case can be relevant between Shmini Atzeret and whenever your country begins requesting rain; alternatively, it can be relevant all "summer" in the southern hemisphere. CYLOR for a final ruling of course ("Local" being extra important here).